# Extend check for cookies by using the post ID

Tags: wordpress, cookies, unique

With the following code I set a cookie:

```
function cta_setcookie($data) {

    //setcookie
    setcookie('cta_'.COOKIEHASH, 'checked', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH);
    return $data;
}
```

and herewith I check if the cookie present:

```
   //check whether user has cookie
   $checked = ( !empty($_COOKIE['cta_'.COOKIEHASH]) && 'checked' == $_COOKIE['cta_'.COOKIEHASH] ) ? true : false;
```

It works, but with this method, the cookie is valid for all sites with my WordPress installation. What I need is to take it only to the actual post.

I tried to add the get_the_ID() function

```
setcookie('cta_'.COOKIEHASH.get_the_ID(), 'checked', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH);
```

to get the cookie unique relative to the post. The cookie is set with the post id, but then the check won´t work. Any attempts failed after adding `the get_the_ID();` to change the check :-(

How should the check be coded now?

Answer (score 0):

get_the_ID() isn't available everywhere.  You might assign it to a value, then echo that, to be sure that you actually have something to work with.

Like:

$myid = get_the_ID();

echo 'My id is '.$myid;

If that works, then you should be able to concatenate it to your cookie and check for that.  IF it's null, then you aren't actually setting the unique value that you are expecting.